# facing issue while opening opening VM using vmware workstation software

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vmware-workstation

I am facing issue while opening vm (cloudera-quickstart-vm-5.13.0-0-vmware) using vmware workstation software (VMware-workstation-full-15.0.2).

when I am trying to play vm/power ON virtual machine, it should start booting/loading but in my case, it is just giving popup of loading and there were no changes on screen. It is not loading/booting VM.

how can i solve this issue?

Comment: if the problem is with the VM, this might be better suited for https://superuser.com

Comment: could you please elaborate your statement?